# obj-c concatenate int issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, concatenation

i'm new to obj-c and i'm trying to code a simple IBAction where a button once clicked change its label. it works good with image background and static string, but when it crashes on this:

```
int i = (arc4random()%90);
NSString *lab = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
[sender setText:lab];
```

why? ty in advance

edit: this is the whole method

```
-(IBAction) toggleUIButtonImage:(id)sender{
    NSString *img = @"bulldog-cute-tom-bancroft.jpg";
    NSString *imgSel = @"kitten-cute-tom-bancroft.jpg";
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:img];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imgSel];
    if ([sender isSelected]) {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }else {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    }

    int i = (arc4random()%90);
    NSString *lab = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    [sender setTitle:lab forState: UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error and bedug log output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the random int or the int2str conversion. It's the way you set the text of your button.
Use this and it should work:

```
[sender setTitle: lab forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

(That is if sender actually is a UIButton of course)

EDIT:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
```

A cast from sender to UIButton* (or any other specific class you want to make respond to the method) is recommended for this as well to ensure you work with the right classmethods.

Comment: post your whole buttonclick method and let me have a look ^^ . Also print out the buglogs and remove the breakpoint so we can have a look at that too.

Comment: You probably want to add a cast from sender to UIButton in the first line of that method.

Comment: uuaaaw! ty mate! :) i'm from web, this is still a bit weird for me eheh :D

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set the title of the UIButton.
For that purpose, you need to use `setTitle:forState:` instead of `setText`.

```
[sender setTitle:lab  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

UIButton reference :[UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Edit:
if `sender` is a type of **id**, change it to UIButton like:

```
UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
```

or simply changing the method signature like:

```
-(IBAction) toggleUIButtonImage:(UIButton *)sender
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either set a reference to the button through Interface Builder being something like:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *buttonName;`

or from the IBAction Method get the button from which it was pressed using:

`UIButton *buttonName = (UIButton *)sender;`

Either way you set the text of the title of a UIButton using the following syntax:
`[buttonName setTitle:lab  forState:UIControlStateNormal];`